How to enable In-App Purchase capability automatically in Expo iOS builds?
I am working on a React Native Expo project and need to enable the In-App Purchase capability in my iOS builds. Currently, I have to manually enable this capability every time I generate a new build using Xcode, which is time-consuming.
Is there a way to configure my project (app.config) so that this capability is automatically added during the build process, without manual intervention in Xcode?
